# Unable to import python-mysqldb

Tags: python, import, mysql

I installed python-mysqldb using

```
sudo apt-get install python-mysqldb
```

I have tried to use it unsuccessfully. The following commands do not work in Python prompt:

```
import python-mysqldb
```

Or

```
import mysqldb
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The package name is "MySQLdb". Case counts.